# Mysql Insert data into multiple table

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1064

I am experiencing a problem in MYSQL insert.
Could any experts will answer this.

Below is my question.

Photo table :

```
pid - PK,
photo_src,
photo_size,
created ,
```

Photo_link table : - for linking more than one image in Blog table .

```
id ,
pid -FK
```

Blog Table :

```
bid - PK,
content,
created,
id - will have photo_link table id .
```

Photo :

```
| pid | photo_src    | photo_size | created             |
+-----+--------------+------------+---------------------+
|   1 | /photo/1.jpg |        400 | 2014-05-27 11:58:45 |
|   2 | /photo/2.jpg |        400 | 2014-05-27 11:58:54 |
|   3 | /photo/3.jpg |        400 | 2014-05-27 11:59:07 |
|   4 | /photo/4.jpg |        400 | 2014-05-27 11:59:14 |
+-----+--------------+------------+---------------------+
```

Photo_link :

```
 +------+------+
 | plid | pid  |
 +------+------+
 |  100 |    1 |
 |  100 |    2 |
 |  100 |    3 |
 |  101 |    2 |
 |  101 |    4 |
 +------+------+
```

Blog Table :

```
+-----+------------------------+---------------------+------+
| bid | content                | created             | pid  |
+-----+------------------------+---------------------+------+
|   1 | This is my first Blog  | 2014-05-27 12:04:44 |  100 |
|   2 | This is my second Blog | 2014-05-27 12:05:01 |  101 |
+-----+------------------------+---------------------+------+
```

Now i have to insert more than one photo into Blog , so first i have to insert the photos for new blog into photo table and again have to insert all the created photo id (pid's) in photo_link table under one id (for each blog one new id is created for photo_link table to save all photos corresponding to that blog) and insert refer that id in blog table.

My problem is how can i get all the newly created photo ids and then insert into photo_link with first time i have to create new id for new blog and then have to save all the corresponding photo with that id and then insert that photo_link id in blog also.

writing procedure may correct ? if it how to write this procedure ?

please give me some idea on this.

please help me on this.It would be great if this can be done .Thanks in advance.

Comment: so you want to do completely in mysql ? why not use the server side language ? also its trigger that needs to be fired after insert on a table.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY` after each insert of the newly created photo in order to get the Id of the inserted photo.

Then you can continue your flow based on the id you got.

Example:

```
DECLARE @insertedId
INSERT INTO Photo(photo_src, photo_size, created) VALUES('/photo/1.jpg', 400, GETDATE())

SELECT @insertedId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

INSERT INTO Photo_link(content, created, pid) VALUES('This is my first Blog', GETDATE(), @insertedId)
```

Comment: Thanks Thanos,could you please give me some example with the above scenerio .

Comment: thanks Thanos for ur response .. I am clear about the first 3 lines but how can i handle the first insert into photo_link and get that id and save all the related photos with that id.

Comment: You need the first bid when you insert in the Photo_link table? Do i understand correctly?

Comment: yes thanos , i need to create the first id for Photo_link table and save the remaining photos for the same blog with that id